# Increasing the sensitivity of a mercury-in-glass thermometer

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I was reading an article covering mercury-in-glass thermometers and it said that having a **smaller mercury bulb** and a **narrower bore** would enable the thermometer to react faster to temperature changes occurring in its environment. How does having those features help the sensitivity of the instrument, from a physics perspective?

Also, am I right to assume that a better range comes at the expense of high sensitivity, due to the fact that the former requires a wider bore and the latter a narrower one?

Comment: Hi. Whenever you want to add points to your question, you want to edit and update your question text rather than adding comments, because comments are deleted after a while (I did it for you already with your last comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really physics principles as much as geometric or math ones in this case.

**Tube Bore:**
This is responsible for resolution. It's the same reason you use a graduated cylinder to measure instead of a beaker. Confining the liquid more in every axis except for the one you are measuring spreads it more out in the direction of the axis of measurement, which results in more in more sensitivity. The mathematician would say that you want to maximize dL/dV is higher where L is the length along the axis of measurement and V is the volume, and narrow shapes do this.

But that means for the same length you have less range. So to recover that range the thermometer or graduated cylinder has to be even longer.

**Bulb Size:**
The bulb is made of thinner glass to promote heat transfer and it's the temperature sensing part of the thermometer. Size affects transient response due to the square cubed law. Larger volume bulb means relatively more liquid not in contact with the surface to exchange heat with the ambient temperature.

On the other hand more volume in the bulb means more liquid in the bulb to expand which means a given temperature change will result in more fluid being squeezed down the tube to travel farther which helps increase sensitivity in face of a larger bore. Like above, this will reduce the range for a given tube length.